# Can I migrate some projects from a gitlab group to a new gitlab group

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have a gitlab group with around 40 projects, sub-groups etc. I need a new gitlab group with some of the projects in the first gitlab group, not all. I see it is possible to migrate gitlab group to another group with all sub-groups included but projects don't get migrated yet. How can I do this? using the API?

Going through this link https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html#migrated-project-resources tells me its possible to migrate groups but not the projects as of now.

Has anyone tried to migrate any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If the groups/projects are on the same GitLab instance, then I recommend you [transfer the project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/tutorials/move_personal_project_to_group/#move-your-project-to-a-group) instead of "migrating".

If you'd like to script it, you can do [transfer projects via the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#transfer-a-project-to-a-new-namespace) as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot transfer as I'd like the projects to be in both the old and new gitlab groups, not just the new gitlab group if that makes sense.

Comment: Well, you said migrate, so I didn't think you'd want to keep a copy in both. The migrate docs you linked to won't keep a copy either. While it's deprecated, the export/import file method is still available. I suggest trying that.